# How does IntelliJ run a Maven project with dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Running a Maven project in IntelliJ is very easy - just declare the dependencies in the POM, and away we go. There is no need to explicitly include the copy-dependencies plugin, assembly plugin, or shade plugin to put the dependency classes and jars somewhere, or to create an executable uber-jar, which would be required if we were to run the application from the command-line or deploying it.

So I'm curious to know how IntelliJ runs my program with dependencies. Does it set the classpath with entries to my dependency classes in the local Maven repository when my running my program?

Since IntelliJ does not invoke the `java` launcher directly - it calls the java launcher API instead - there is no "command" for us to see.